# Problema al subir fichero FTP JAVA

Tags: java, ftp

Buenas,

Estoy intentando subir un archivo a un servidor mediante FTP:

```
 try{
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(server);
        if(!ftp.login(username, password)){
            ftp.logout();
        }
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
            ftp.disconnect();
        }

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(ruta);
        ftp.setFileType(ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.setFileTransferMode(ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.storeFile("cartel"+t+".txt", in);
        in.close();
        ftp.logout();
        ftp.disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Funciona todo correctamente (establece conexión, hace el login correctamente y se sube el fichero) pero el programa se queda parado en el momento que hace storeFile. Se queda como si no acabara nunca la instrucción y no sigue el programa. He visto en varios foros y varias páginas que todo el mundo lo hace igual.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar ocurriendo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: mh ... por casualidad ese fichero con ese nombre existe ya?

Comment: Puedes subir el Stack Trace de la consola por favor, para ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas

Podrías probar utilizar el método alterno siguiente (*storeFileStream*):

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
boolean transferido = false;
String nombreArchivo = "cartel" + t +".txt"; // de donde viene 't'?
String ftpServer = "servidorFtp";

try {
    // establecemos un tiempo limite de espera para acciones
    ftp.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    ftp.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(60);
    ftp.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(3000);
    ftp.connect(ftpServer);

    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode()))
        throw new Exception(String.format("Conexion no realizada > Codigo: %s", ftp.getReplyCode()));

    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    boolean bLoginOk = ftp.login(user, password);

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
    OutputStream outputStream = ftp.storeFileStream(remoteFile);

    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
    int read = 0;

    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1)
        outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);

    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();

    transferido = ftp.completePendingCommand();

    // si no se envio
    if (!transferido)
        throw new Exception(String.format("Archivo %s no tranferido!", nombreArchivo));

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Error enviando archivo a [" + ftpServer + "] Detalles: " + e.getMessage());

} finally {
    try {
        if (ftp.isConnected()) {
            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw ioe;
    }
}
```